# Android flashlight app crashes every other launch

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to app development and wanted to make a simple flashlight app for fun. However, for some reason my flashlight app crashes every other launch. I thought I might need an `onDestroy()` method, but not sure if that's the problem. I also always get a `NullPointerException` and the problem seems to be within the `onCreate()` method. Thanks for any help!

```
package com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    //Camera variables:
    private Camera camera;
    ImageButton flashlightSwitchImg;
    private boolean isFlashLightOn;
    Parameters params;


    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;


    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };

    private View mControlsView;
    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };
    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });


        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        //TODO: uncoment? findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);

        //Camera Stuff's old spot
        //Camera Stuff:
        flashlightSwitchImg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flashlightSwitch);
        boolean isCameraFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().
                hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        if(!isCameraFlash) {
            showNoCameraAlert();
        } else {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        }

        flashlightSwitchImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isFlashLightOn) {
                    setFlashLightOff();
                } else {
                    setFlashLightOn();
                }
            }


        });
    }

    private void showNoCameraAlert() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Error: No Camera Flash Found!!").
                setMessage("Camera flashlight not available in this Android device!").
                setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
        return;
    }

    //setFlashLightOn
    private void setFlashLightOn() {
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashLightOn = true;
        flashlightSwitchImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_on);
    }

    //setFlashLightOff
    private void setFlashLightOff() {
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashLightOn = false;
        flashlightSwitchImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_off);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }
    //end Camera stuff




    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
05-11 15:11:39.793 18729-18729/com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight D/Activity: #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
05-11 15:11:40.583 18729-18729/com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
05-11 15:11:40.653 18729-18729/com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-11 15:11:40.653 18729-18729/com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d01da0)
05-11 15:11:40.653 18729-18729/com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight, PID: 18729
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight.FullscreenActivity.setFlashLightOn(FullscreenActivity.java:173)
  at com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight.FullscreenActivity.access$700(FullscreenActivity.java:24)
  at com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight.FullscreenActivity$6.onClick(FullscreenActivity.java:150)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4754)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19591)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5731)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 15:11:41.773 18729-18729/com.monstartech.superuser.flashlight 

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18729 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The `NullPointerException` in your stack would appear to come from `camera` being undefined yet. Not sure how, though, because from first glance this can only appear when it has no flash, but you exit in this case anyway...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Logcat, the app is crashing at line 173, which looks like it is this line:

```
params = camera.getParameters();
```

So your camera variable is probably null. So check for a null camera. You can probably use the same logic  from line 137 to initialize the camera.

```
private void setFlashLightOn() {
    if (camera == null) {
        // make isCameraFlash a class level variable
        if(!isCameraFlash) {
            showNoCameraAlert();
        } else {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        }
    }

    params = camera.getParameters();
    // etc
```

Answer (score 3):

You are nulling out the camera `onStop`, but not recreating the camera object `onStart`. I would just cancel the camera but not make it null `onStop`.

`onStop` doesn't mean your app is destroyed. It will be restarted as you left it, in this case with a null camera object.